# UML Class Diagram -- Multiplicity for Inheritance

Tags: inheritance, uml, class-diagram

My understanding is that, in UML class diagrams, inheritance is a particular kind of association.

An association can have a multiplicity.

However, it seems that inheritance is never represented with a multiplicity.

Why?
Is it because the multiplicity is always `1..1` and `0..1` (example below)?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> inheritance is a particular kind of association

This is a fundamental misunderstanding. Generalization (aka inheritance) is a particular kind of **relationship** but it is not an **association**.

Thus there is no multiplicity for it. Also as already mentioned it would make no sense to have one.

Generalization is on a class level. If a class B is a specialized class of class A, then all elements that are of type B are at the same type also of type A.